# Creating a Django model to track monthly employee meetings

Tags: python, django

I am looking to create multiple models using Django so that I can track monthly meetings with an employee. Each employee could have multiple meetings each month. I am struggling with how to create my models in a way that I can display the data in a template like so:

```
Month 1            Meeting1              Meeting2
employee1          notes here            more notes
employee2          ''                    ''

Month 2            Meeting1              Meeting2
employee1          notes                 notes
employee2          ''                    ''
```

So my current model setup is this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name

class Month(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.number


class Meeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='meetings')
    notes = models.TextField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='employee meetings')
```

I can access the data I need fairly easy in code, however am unable to find a way to iterate through the data easily in the template. Is there an easier solution that I am missing, or a better way to create the models. Additionally, would you be able to suggest a good DBMS book for a better understanding of the database relationships?

Comment: Try a `models.ManyToManyField()` for your Employee-Meeting relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Adam, but I'm not sure how the manytomanyfield will be of help.  There is not going to be an instance where a single meeting belongs to multiple employees only an employee with multiple meetings.   It still leaves the problem of how I would access the meetings from a specific month for an employee through a template.

Comment: I would question your requirement. You seem to be making it hard on yourself for no real reason, and actually making this unscalable. Why not simply have an index page just showing a line per month, maybe with the number of meetings that exist for that month. When the user click, say, month 2, then you take them to some /month/2 URL where you can now easily remove one dimension, making this a matter of iterating through all employees and filtering by month=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using regroup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).  I haven't tested the code below, but something like this could work:

```
<ul>
{% regroup meetings by month as month_list %}
{% for month in month_list %}
    <li>{{ month.grouper.number }}
    {% for item in month.list %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ item.employee.name }}: {{ item.notes }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work for the issue presented. I was unfamiliar with the regroup template tag. This does present its own problem - if an employee has not yet had a meeting, they will not be listed, but this gives me a direction to look. I will mark this as solved.